# Admob with Cordova 3 and Google play services

Tags: android, cordova, admob, google-play-services, cordova-3

I am trying to get AdMob on my Phonegap/Cordova 3 application but not sure if I am using the correct plugin.
I have tried these two plugins below but cant seem to get them to work. I am just wondering if someone could confirm these plugins are working with latest Cordova 3 and google play services.

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-admob
https://github.com/aliokan/cordova-plugin-admob

These plugins seem to be using Admob plugin but now Android uses Google play services so is there a confirmed phonegap plugin for android using Google play services with AdMob?

Comment: Have you managed to get AdMob working in your app?  I've tried a bunch of plugins and all of them seem to be targetting older versions of Phonegap/Cordova.